# How do you fix one of my images is not loading after another is loaded?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, onload

An overall explanation of my code is that I am making an animation. I have 3 canvases, one for the base image, one for the streamline wind map drawing, and the last one an image that is covering up part of the drawing. My code below shows the two images being uploaded..

```
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            var cvrimg = document.createElement("cvrimg");
            img.src = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img.png";
            cvrimg.scr = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img-two.png";
            img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
            cvrimg.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
            img.onload = function () {
                imgctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
                cvrimg.onload = function () {
                    console.log("maybe");
                    cvrctx.drawImage(cvrimg,10,10);
                    startDrawing(wdDataArr,wsDataArr,dataManArr,pastDataArr,onlineArr);
                }
            }
```

I put some log statements in the code and the `cvrimg.onload` function is not being called. The network tab in the inspect tool on chrome only shows one image being queried.

Any advice is appreciated for this novice programmer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `cvrimg.onload` function only when `img.onload` is called. If `cvrimg` is loaded before `img.onload` is called, it wouldn't call the function, because it's simply not deifned.

Also, `cvrimg = document.createElement("cvrimg")` creates `<cvrimg>` element, which makes no sense.

**Option 1** – parallel loading

```js
let img = document.createElement("img"),
    cvrimg = document.createElement("img");

img.src = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img.png";
cvrimg.scr = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img-two.png";

img.onload = function() {
    console.log("img loaded");
    ...
}

cvrimg.onload = function() {
    console.log("cvrimg loaded");
    ...
}
```

**Option 2** – serial loading

```js
let img = document.createElement("img"),
    cvrimg = document.createElement("img");

img.src = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img.png";

img.onload = function() {
    console.log("img loaded, loading cvrimg now");
    cvrimg.scr = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.example.com/img-two.png";
    ...
}

cvrimg.onload = function() {
    console.log("cvrimg loaded");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those methods and the first image loads, but the second one is not requested. Do you have any other recommendations? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your `cvrimg` variable is an `<img>` and not `<cvrimg>` element? Also, are you sure the second img's src is available? Does it throw anything on `cvrimg.onerror`?